# Is there a way to use global property in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a scheduler that puts some value(N or Y) into a topic for every 10 mins(usually 'N', unless something abnormal happens with topic). When the topic goes down, the scheduler will populate a property(kind of inter-scheduler communication), so that it can be used during scheduler's next cycle, as way of telling the scheduler that something bad happened during last cycle, so that, it'll place a different value('Y') in topic in this cycle. But the problem here is normal exchange property isn't helping. The property is always null during every scheduler cycle.

When i went through the http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd, looking out for something similar to global properties, i got this one **"tns:properties"**
which can be set at context level.
Can this be used as a global property?
is there a way to read/write it in my scheduler route?

I'm also thinking about having a bean with an instance variable to hold this inter-scheduler-communication property.

Can anyone suggest the right option?

Answer (score 0):

What you've described sounds to me like a means for maintaining state between processes, and using the properties for that will be problematic for a number of reasons.

I suggest breaking the app into a couple different pieces, and use a shared OSGi service to maintain the state.

```
public interface MyScheduleState() {
   public setSomeValue(String x)
   public String getSomeValue()
}
```

Route 1: Timer starts the task .. check the service for values.. send event.  if error occurs, sends error message to some queue://MY.ERRORS

Route 2: Listen for errors on MY.ERRORS and update the OSGi service with new values

This gives you control over the behavior and you can change how the "stateful service" stores its data.. either in memory, on disk as a file or in a cache" and your routes will never know the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to http://camel.apache.org/properties.html

It seems to be exactly you are looking for - context properties. You can set a property value on each cycle and it will be available in the next cycle too.